# Using array_map on the fetch_assoc method of a MySQLi query

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Say I've got the following code:

```
$mysqli=new MySQLi('localhost', 'blah', 'blah', 'blah');
$articles=$mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `articles`");
$articles_row=array_map('stripslashes', $articles->fetch_assoc());
```

I'd get a message saying that "argument 2 expects an array".

Is using array_map in this way considered bad practice, and why? Why will it give an error?

Comment: From what you have, it appears that your query didn't return a result.  Though, why are you running `stripslashes` on the results from the database?

Comment: Because, if I've escaped them with $mysqli->real_escape_string(), it appears to add backslashes. It happens if it returns multiple rows.

Comment: If that function added slashes to the DB, that most likely means that you have [Magic Quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) enabled - you want to make sure those are disabled. ^^

Comment: And how would I do that? And what should it do, instead?

Comment: Click the link above and read ^^ Or go to [Disabling Magic Quotes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php).  When inserting data into the database, it should make it so you don't need to `stripslashes` after you retrieve the information. Magic Quotes screws up normal sanitizing. Magic Quotes is considered a bad thing and was subsequently removed as of PHP 5.4 because of this idiocy it causes.

Comment: Thanks! What should real_escape_string normally do, instead?

Comment: `real_escape_string` does its own version of `addslashes` so that it is 'safe' to insert data in to the database without SQL Injection.  You want to keep that if you aren't using prepared queries - but you definitely want to make sure 'Magic Quotes' is disabled in `php.ini` or at runtime with the code provided on the previous link. ^^

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27742/discussion-between-connor-gurney-and-jon)

Answer (score 0):

Try this and remember to store your data.

```
$mysqli=new MySQLi('localhost', 'blah', 'blah', 'blah');
if ($result=$mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `articles`")){
  if ($result->num_rows >= 1){
    $articles = array() ; //Create a storage
    while($article = $result->fetch_assoc()){
      $articles[] = array_map("stripslashes", $article) ; //Call the function for each row
    }
  } else
    echo "No rows" ;
} else 
  echo "Fail query" ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't apply any stripslashes on the data you've got from database.
You should not add them in the first place.

It seems that you are using prepared statements, which makes escaping useless. And thus get escaped data in the database (which is wrong).

So, just don't use `$mysqli->real_escape_string()` on the data you are adding via prepared statement, and you won't need no stripslashes ever.